# Loop script if -loop $true passed by named parameters

Tags: loops, powershell

I would like to loop my script if started with `myscript.ps1 -loop -seconds 20`
(seconds would be the start-sleep inbetween each loop).

- The script is quite complex and i dot source two other scriptfiles
  (one for functions and one for settings).
- I prompt for password with `$password = Read-Host "Enter password" -AsSecureString` in the script so I don't think I can have a kicker/launcher-script without loosing the $password variable making me input the pwd each loop..

How would I go about looping the script and ONLY loop if `-loop`is passed as a named parameter?

Should I put the entire script in a while-loop or what would the best way be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a do .. while loop e.g.:

```
# Dot source other scripts
# Ask for and store password in a variable
do {
    ... # this stuff happens once or until Ctrl+C depending on $loop switch
    if ($loop) { Start-Sleep -sec $seconds }
} while ($loop)
```

Although rather than a loop switch perhaps you'd be better off with a loop count that defaults to 1?

Comment: Fantastic! This is exactly what I'm after! But what do you mean by a "loop count that defaults to 1" ? Should I not use a named parameter? Oh, and thanks for [Effective Windows PowerShell: The Free eBook](http://cid-5a8d2641e0963a97.office.live.com/self.aspx/Public/Effective%20Windows%20PowerShell.pdf)  by the way. A great contribution to the community!

Comment: You could consider a parameter like this: `function foo($LoopCount = 1, $seconds = 20) { do {...} while (--$LoopCount) }` then when invoked as just `foo` the code executes just once but if executed as `foo -loopCount 10` it would loop ten times, sleeping for 20 seconds on each iteration.

Comment: That's what I ended up with as well. But I used a `$i++` inside my loop and checked with `while ($loop -gt $i)`. How does your `--$loopcount` work?

Comment: do/while loops always execute once and then check the terminating condition.  `--$loopCount` decrements the count before testing it.  As long as that evaluates to non-zero the loop doesn't terminate.